# SimpleXML - simplexml_load_file()

Tags: php, simplexml

I can't load a XML file with SimpleXML. I am always trying the function simplexml_load_file, but it doesn't work. Here is my PHP-Code:

```
$filezilla = 'G:/xampp/FileZillaFTP/FileZilla Server.xml';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($filezilla) or die ("Failure");

Output: Failure
```

I also looked in the php.ini and allow_url_fopen is activated.
Bizzarely, this code works:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://api.wefeelfine.org:8080/ShowFeelings?display=xml&feeling=happy&returnfields=imageid,feeling,sentence,posttime,postdate,posturl,gender,country,state,city,lat,lon&limit=0&extraimages=20');
print_r($xml);
```

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: Did you try loading the file whitout a file protocol, and with a filename without spaces.

Comment: wrap your code with `if (file_exists($filezilla)) {//try your code.}`

Comment: The file exists, but i can't load it with simplexml. I also tried to open the xml file with $file = file($filezilla); and this worked.

Comment: Yes, I also tried to load the file without spaces, but also a failure

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem while trying to do this locally, code worked find on the host.